# VFP SFTP cannot connect through port 6022

Tags: port, sftp

We have successfully been connecting using SFTP over port 22.  The target server is changing to use port 6022 and the SFTP connection is failing. 
We can successfully connect through SFTP on port 6022 using Filezilla. 
Chilkat works if we go back to port 22.
We are using the most recent release of the ActiveX dll.

Please note: I am NOT versed in the details of SFTP and how it works.

Here is the log being returned from the connection attempt:

```
The FSC SFTP connection to download files failed for /Targetfolder/.  Verify IP address for the connection. The Chilkat message is ChilkatLog:
  Connect_SFtp:
    DllDate: Feb 24 2020
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.82
    UnlockPrefix: OURSSH
    Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
    Language: ActiveX
    VerboseLogging: 0
    SftpVersion: 0
    hostname: targetserver.com
    port: 6022
    connectInner:
      sshConnect:
        connectSocket:
          connect_ipv6_or_ipv4:
           Connection attempt failed.
            maxWaitTimeMs: 20000
            totalMsWaitedSoFar: 16800
          --connect_ipv6_or_ipv4
        --connectSocket
        Failed to establish initial TCP/IP connection
        hostname: targetserver.com
        port: 6022
      --sshConnect
    --connectInner
    Failed.
  --Connect_SFtp
--ChilkatLog
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved - turns out the incorrect port was provided for the connection.  When we corrected the port the connection worked fine.